# Keywords tagging in .net - similar to youtube tagging

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I tried to generate the keywords as buttons, but how do I get the X in the button so that it can be removed by user?

http://blog.pond5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Screen-Shot-2015-03-30-at-11.46.46-AM.png

Thanks

Comment: Context? How are you rendering the keywords? Are you asking about HTML/CSS styling or how to add a tagging taxonomic system to an existing database?

Comment: HTML/CSS styling. I am ok with database part.

Comment: What markup do you have right now? You haven't shown us anything besides a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: And if this is a HTML/CSS question, please remove the asp.net tags on this question and add HTML and CSS tags.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't have a button within a button.** I would suggest one of two approaches to get a similar effect:

**1. Forget about the "X" and make the whole button function as "Delete".**

This is the easiest approach. Leave your buttons as they are, create an event handler for their click event to delete the tag (as you seem to have been planning to do with the "X" click), and possibly clarify a little to your user that clicking a tag will delete it.

**2. Place an "X" button and a label for the tag name, possibly within a a container (such as a groupbox).**

This takes slightly more effort but gets the functionality much closer to what you want. The label shows the tag name, the button is labeled "X", and clicking the button removes both (or the container, if you prefer that look). If you haven't already created a custom class for your tags, it would probably be worth doing so and declaring these controls as properties.